# How can I make this button have two click events?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My program so far will create these nested divs with an image in the inner most div over and over.

I know I can make more than one event happen on the same click but in this case i need them to happen one after the other. so click#1 will result in the nest divs and image#1 but click#2 will result in the nest divs and image#2. click#3 will show image#1 and so on. The even clicks will show the even image, odd shows the odd. i

dk if all of the divs need to be created again or just the image needs to be swapped.

if it helps (havent attmepted so i didnt want to ask yet)....ultimately i need to also create a text box that keeps track of the amount of clicks and uses the current textbox value  to change the images.

```js
var i = 0;

function runTogether1() 
  {
    addDiv();
    addDiv2();
    addDiv3();
    addbutterfly();
  }


function addDiv() 
  {
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.classList.add('div1');
    document.body.appendChild(div1);
  }

function addDiv2() 
  {
    var div2 = document.createElement('div');
    div2.classList.add('div2');
    document.getElementsByClassName("div1")[i].appendChild(div2);
  }

function addDiv3() 
  {
    var div3 = document.createElement('div');
    div3.classList.add('div3');
    document.getElementsByClassName("div2")[i].appendChild(div3);
  }

function addbutterfly() 
{
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "gorilla.bmp";
document.getElementsByClassName("div3")[i].appendChild(img);
i++;
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 1em;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: limegreen;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
}


div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src ="gorillajs.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="button">
      <button onclick = "runTogether1()"> 
          click to get nested divs
      </button>  
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't place javascript inline of the HTML, e.g. use addEventLitsteners instead of onclick=x as this makes coding easier. Don't duplicate similar code when you can do the same by updating a variable. E.g. your functions are all the same except a number, 1, 2, 3, you can replace this with a single function and pass in a variable value which can be 1, 2, or 3 instead. To go from 1 to 2 to 1 to 2, you can use the modulo operator '%' e.g. `int%2`. Sorry I can't answer the question exactly I don't fully understand and your question isn't formulated in an understandable way.

Answer (score 1):

Create a global boolean variable that you toggle each time you run the `runTogether().` When it's true, run your "odd" function, then set the toggle to false, otherwise, run your "even" function and set your toggle to true.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, this makes sense to me. I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the very first click to create the divs and image, and show a specific image, and then subsequent clicks to keep the same divs as they are, but just swap the image out?

If that is the case, the simplest way to accomplish this would be to retain a reference to the `<img>` tag, or otherwise add an attribute such as an `id` so you can run `document.getElementById(...)` to find the *existing* `<img>` tag in your click event handler... In your simplified example you could use `getElementsByTagName('img')[0]` as well.

To swap the image content, you need only to change the `img.src` property.

You can use the `%` (modulo) operator to handle the odd/even determination, which basically returns the remainder of the two numbers, so `1%2=1`, `2%2=0`, `3%2=1`, etc. This means `i%2` would always return `0` for an even value and `1` for an odd value.

```
function runTogether1() 
  {
    // Initial Call, create elements
    if (i === 0) {
      addDiv();
      addDiv2();
      addDiv3();
      addbutterfly();
    } else {
      var img = document.getElementByTagName('img')[0];
      if ((i % 2) === 0) {
        img.src = 'even-image-src.jpg';
      } else {
        img.src = 'odd-image-src.jpg';
      }
    }
  }
```